# How to erase .lof file (and other auxiliary files) in Overleaf?

Tags: floats, compiling, overleaf

I am working on the [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com) collaborative platform. I am facing the following error code :

```
./main.lof:18: 
Missing $ inserted. 
<inserted text> $ 
l.18 ...some figure_name}}{23}{figure.17}
```

The thing is, even after correcting/deleting the figure that causes this error, the compilation will always stop on this.

From my understanding, I would need to erase the .lof file to avoid this error again but I do not know how to access it on the overleaf platform. 
Do you think I undersand well the situation? Do you know how to access the .lof file?

Answer (score 25):

## Overleaf v1

If you click on the "compile error" or "warning" label on the upper right, that should display the error message or warning message window (if it's not already open). There's a `recompile from scratch` option at the bottom of this message window; you can click on that to delete the auxiliary files (`.aux`, `.toc`, `.lof`...)

## Overleaf v2

Click on the "Logs and other files" icon next to the "Recompile" button, then scroll right to the bottom, and click on the Trashcan icon.

Comment: Screenshots at https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Clearing_the_cache

Answer (score 0):

There is an icon of error and warning in the upper right corner. Scroll down to bottom of the warning and error. You will see a trash icon and click on that icon. Then click on clear the cache. It works for me.