# Overleaf does not compile after using Biblatex

Tags: biblatex, errors, compiling, overleaf

I have my PhD deadline on Monday and disaster has struck at the very last minute! Any assistance would be eternally appreciated.

I'm using Overleaf (v2) to write my thesis - it's a very large file tree containing multiple `.tex` files.

Everything was compiling fine, until I decided to experiment and use:

```
\usepackage{biblatex}
```

It compiled with this included but looked odd, so I deleted the line again. However, now it does not compile - despite the document being exactly the same as before the problem began.

Comment: Don't know overleaf, but in other latex environments it can change things if you delete the *.aux file and possibly other files that were generated during compilation

Comment: this is a question best answered by the CS of overleaf. They are very quick to respond. Please contact them.

Answer (score 11):

If you changed your bibliography package from a BibTeX-based solution to `biblatex` or vice versa it is not at all unlikely that there would be some errors due to left over auxiliary files. BibTeX and Biber use these files to communicate with LaTeX (see [Question mark or bold citation key instead of citation number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864) for a great explanation), but the format of that file and its precise usage differs between `biblatex` and standard BibTeX. If the `.bbl` was produced for one method it will not be usable for the other.  Usually `latexmk` (the tool Overleaf uses to compile your TeX document automatically) is quite good at sorting out issues like this, but sometimes it gets stuck with old file versions. In that case it helps to clear the auxiliary files (Overleaf calls this 'clearing the cache').

It is generally safe to delete the temporary files and recompile from scratch. **Note that this answer also applies to a more general situation that does not involve switching between `biblatex` and BibTeX, but where the issue simply is caused by bad auxiliary files.**

You can clear the auxiliary files via the following steps.

Click on the 'Logs and output files' button next to the *Recompile* button on the top of the rightmost pane, it will probably show the number of errors in a red box (highlighted in light pink in the screenshot).

[image: The 'Logs and output files' button]

You will be greeted with a digest of all error messages and warnings that LaTeX and other auxiliary programs like BibTeX or Biber reported. Scroll down to the bottom of the page. On the bottom right you'll see a little dustbin icon (highlighted in blue). Its hover-text says 'Clear cached files'. That button allows you to get rid of all temporary auxiliary files (`.aux`, `.bbl`, `.bcf`, ...).

[image: Dustbin icon]

A popup messages asks you to confirm.

[image: Confirm dialogue]

If you press "Clear cache" in that window, Overleaf deletes all your temporary files. You can then recompile and the error should be gone.

Comment: Related, but without pictures, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/303806/35864

Comment: Also https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Clearing_the_cache but you have very nice screenshots! :-)