# Can't include references with biblatex

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I have no idea what's going on. I'm trying to write my assignment in Latex but the references are not showing up. I put this on the preamble:

```latex
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{ref.bib}
```

My folder is split into different files, so I have this on the main file:

```latex
\import{sections/}{Referencias}
```

And in the file Referencias.tex I have this:

```
\section*{\centering REFERÊNCIAS}
\printbibliography
```

My file ref.bib has the Biblatex reference like so:

```
@book{NISE:2013,
  author    = {Norman S. Nise}, 
  title     = {Engenharia de sistemas de controle},
  publisher = {LTC},
  year      = {2013},
  address   = {Rio de Janeiro},
  edition   = {6},
}

@book{OGATA:2010,
  author    = {Katsuhiko Ogata}, 
  title     = {Engenharia de controle moderno},
  publisher = {Pearson Prentice Hall},
  year      = {2010},
  address   = {São Paulo},
  edition   = {5},
}

@misc{Deepanshu:2016,
  author = {Deepanshu Singh, Himanshu Jain }
  title = {Reinforcement Learning},
  howpublished = {\url{http://courseprojects.souravsengupta.com/cds2016/reinforcement-learning/}},
  note = {Accessed: 2019-04-14}
}
```

and I cite it like this:

```
\cite{Deepanshu:2016}
```

But the references won't show up. If anyone could give me a hand or point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated, because honestly, I don't even know what to Google to solve this.

**EDIT**

So, this is the output of my .blg file:

```
[0] Config.pm:302> INFO - This is Biber 2.9
[0] Config.pm:305> INFO - Logfile is '0_0_Arquivo_Principal.blg'
[23] biber:313> INFO - === Sat Apr 20, 2019, 18:31:16
[43] Biber.pm:371> INFO - Reading '0_0_Arquivo_Principal.bcf'
[103] Biber.pm:857> INFO - Found 5 citekeys in bib section 0
[113] Biber.pm:3981> INFO - Processing section 0
[123] Biber.pm:4154> INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'ref.bib' for section 0
[123] bibtex.pm:1468> INFO - LaTeX decoding ...
[131] bibtex.pm:1294> INFO - Found BibTeX data source 'ref.bib'
[164] Utils.pm:169> WARN - ISBN '1886529302, 9781886529304' in entry 'Bertsekas:2007:DPO:1396348' is invalid - run biber with '--validate_datamodel' for details.
[169] Utils.pm:185> ERROR - BibTeX subsystem: /tmp/6CNc3TdK7G/ref.bib_9127.utf8, line 21, syntax error: found "title", expected end of entry ("}" or ")") (skipping to next "@")
[169] Biber.pm:110> INFO - WARNINGS: 1
[169] Biber.pm:114> INFO - ERRORS: 1
```

And here are the parts from the log file

```
Package biblatex Warning: Conflicting options.
(biblatex)                '<namepart>inits' conflicts with 'uniquename=full'.
(biblatex)                Setting 'uniquename=init' on input line 112.

Package amsmath Warning: Foreign command \over;
(amsmath)                \frac or \genfrac should be used instead
(amsmath)                 on input line 39.

LaTeX Warning: Citation 'DBLP:journals/corr/abs-1806-07366' on page 3 undefined
 on input line 62.

LaTeX Warning: Citation 'wiki:File:Lorenz_attractor_yb.svg' on page 5 undefined
 on input line 119.

LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `T1/ptm/bx/n' in size <10.95> not available
(Font)              Font shape `T1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 119.

LaTeX Warning: Citation 'wiki:File:Lorenz_attractor_yb.svg' on page 5 undefined
 on input line 119.

LaTeX Warning: Citation 'Deepanshu:2016' on page 6 undefined on input line 145.

LaTeX Warning: Citation 'Deepanshu:2016' on page 6 undefined on input line 145.


LaTeX Warning: Citation 'Bertsekas:2007:DPO:1396348' on page 6 undefined on inp
ut line 149.

LaTeX Warning: Citation 'Wolfram2002' on page 6 undefined on input line 155.

LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 7.

LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.


Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file:
(biblatex)                0_0_Arquivo_Principal
(biblatex)                and rerun LaTeX afterwards.
```

Comment: Did you run the normal cycle: `pdflatex > biber > pdflatex (twice)`?

Comment: I've simply compiled with the Overleaf compile button, is that it?

Comment: I don't know  Overleaf, so I can't tell. Do you have a .bbl and a .blg files?

Comment: no, are they generated when compiling? Sorry, this is my first time using biblatex.

Comment: The entry `Deepanshu:2016` is malformed. There are two issues: (1) Multiple names must be separated with an `and` not a comma, regardless of the desired output (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36396/35864). (2) There must be a comma after the field (it is omissible after the last field in an entry). So you should have `author = {Deepanshu Singh and Himanshu Jain},`. This will definitely stop *this* entry from showing up, but the others should be displayed.

Comment: You should also be using the `url` and `urldate` field instead of `howpublished` and `note`: `url = {http://courseprojects.souravsengupta.com/cds2016/reinforcement-learning/}, urldate = {2019-04-14},`

Comment: Fix the two errors mentioned in my comment above. Then recompile your project from scratch, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/479736/35864. Then you can access the **`.blg`** file as described in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/462314/35864 for the *`.bbl`* file. Download the **`.blg`** and the **`.log`**. Post the complete `.blg` here and post all parts of the `.log` that mention warnings or errors.

Comment: Ok, I've fixed the errors and posted the ```.blg``` and ```.log```

Comment: Solved, damn you freaking comma!!!!

Answer (score 1):

I solved thanks to the comments and just wanted to leave it here if it is of any help. As one can see in the `.blg` file it was missing a comma after author in the `.bib` file. I could not have noticed it by compiling with overleaf since I can't see this file from there, I solved it, compiled from scratch and it works like a charm, but for some strange reason the same fix does not work on overleaf.