# Bibliography will not recognize one source

Tags: biblatex, citing, overleaf

I have an issue with my `.bib` in LaTeX. I just started using it and can't figure out what's wrong. I am using the site Overleaf to create my documents. Basically, I have a bibliography like so:

```
@online{1234,
author = "Lexikon der Physik",
title = "Kompensationsmethode",
url = "https://www.spektrum.de/lexikon/physik/kompensationsmethode/8214",
addendum = "(Stand: 30.05.2019)",
}


@online{anleitung,
    author = "Elektrizitätslehre Institut für Angewandte Physik der Goethe-Universität Frankfurt am Main",
    title = "Anleitung zu Versuch 5",
    url = "http://www.uni-frankfurt.de/49295171/Generic_49295171.pdf",
    addendum = "(Stand: 30.05.2019)",
}
```

In total there are 6 sources.
My subfile in which I am citing goes somewhat like this:

```
\subsection{Kompensationsmethode}

blablabla text \cite{1234} \cite{anleitung}. more text
```

Now, the 1234 one will not be recognized, I have tried naming it differently, moving it to a different position in the `.bib` file and it just will not find it. Instead it will give me the [1234] instead of the actual citation within the PDF.

[image: not recognised cite]

The error message is:

[image: error message]

I have absolutely no clue why one of my sources is being recognized, and the other one is not. Any help is apreciated.

Comment: As I am using Overleaf, i shouldnt have to run Biber, as it is included, and should do so automaticly when compiling. I dont think Biber can be run manually with Overleaf. Right now any new source that i am adding, wont be recognised. I just cant figure out why it stopped working suddenly

Comment: yeah, i have tried several names, the first one i used was "komp" then "methode", none of these work

Comment: I have created a copy of the original file using Overleaf, the copy compiles just fine, it seems to be an issue with Overleaf itself. I still need the original file to compile though, so any ideas would be great.

Comment: I dont think it´s a formatting issue. I have just copied the entire project, and the copy compiles, whereas the original one wont. I just dont know how i can force Overleaf to run Biber, as that seems to be the issue

Comment: no, the renaming doesent work. right now any newly added source will not show up. I will try and contact Overleaf and see if they can fix the issue.

Comment: The entries work OK if I embed them into a minimal example document: https://gist.github.com/moewew/f177f4616d561323580d0b879763b1ea. They are not ideal and and could be improved: https://gist.github.com/moewew/8915ed49c9e26ead17def5eec4a1aa6f (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10808/35864 and note the use of `urldate`). Try if those examples work for you and report back. Please also try to come up with a similar small example document that shows exactly what you are doing: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864.

Comment: You'll definitely want to clean the cache (https://de.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Clearing_the_cache) and recompile from scratch. And then please show us the `.blg` and `.log` file (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/462314/35864 shows how to get the `.bbl`, we need the **`.blg`** and **`.log`**).

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out:
After contacting the support they told me, that Overleaf might not run Biber, as the Outputs are still cached. By clearing it, Biber will run again. 
For anyone wondering how to do so and having the same issue, here is how to clear the cache: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Clearing_the_cache

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/479736/35864

Comment: But please note that the entries have issues that should probably be resolved. https://gist.github.com/moewew/8915ed49c9e26ead17def5eec4a1aa6f shows what I would suggest (I prefer `{...}` over `"..."` as field delimiters, but for most intents and purposes the two forms are equivalent and you can use whichever you prefer. But do note the double curly braces, if you want to stick to `"..."` you'd have to say `author = "{Lexikon der Physik}",`)

Comment: Thank you for your advice, i too prefer {} over the "", I am going to change that. As i have just today started using Biber i am still figuring things out. the "urldate" is great, but as i am writing my paper in german it is kindof weird to have  "visited on" in english. Is there a way to set it to german? i have done it manually bevore by using "Stand: date"

Comment: If you write a German document you should probably load `babel` (`\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}`). Then `biblatex` will automatically switch to the main document language (which would be German in your case). If you only just started you may want to have a look at one of the guides/tutorials in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13509/35864 to make yourself familiar with `biblatex` and Biber.

Comment: yeah, the babel fixed that. I had a \usepackage{german}, I thought that did the same thing...
I´ll look into the bib guide

Comment: `\usepackage{german}` is terribly outdated, unmaintained and will actually give you the pre-*Rechtschreibreform* rules. `babel` is a much better bet and nowadays you are probably required to adhere to the *Rechtschreibreform*, so `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}` it is. If a source recommends `\usepackage{german}`, you should be extremely wary of that source: It is either severely outdated or just bad. (Of course you should in general not believe everything a random person on the internet, who may or may not pretend to be a TeXpert, tells you. Sometimes it is good to double check.)