# Problem with adding references to my thesis

Tags: biblatex

I am writing my thesis in Overleaf and on compilation it gives me a warning, which says: Using fall-back BibTeX(8) backend: functionality may be reduced/unavailable.
I understand it is because I am using BibTex as my backend instead of Biber. However, my problem is that after the file is complied, it only shows me one of my references and not the other one.

Example of my document is below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=authoryear,natbib=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{References.bib}
\title{problem with references}
\author{abc }
\date{August 2019}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Introduction}
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc,title={References}]
\end{document}
```

Is there any way I can use to show all the references?
Note: In particular, my file does not show any references with a template of @misc

Edit: I forgot to add the `\addbibresource{}` to my example here. But it is there in my file. I didn't have any resources cited in my `main.tex` file. When I compile the file, it generates one of the resources on its own. However, when I add `\cite{Reference1}` `\cite{Reference2}` at the end on my main file it prints both of my resources. But it prints both of my references twice. First with their whole description and then just their title. I'm not sure how can I solve it. 
[image: screenshot of my result]

Comment: Unless you have very strong reasons not to use `biber` you should *not* use `bibtex` as the backend for `biblatex`.   But your sample document doesn't cite anything. Are you using `\cite` or `\textcite` etc for the references that don't show up?  What does the `.blg` file say?  And you have to tell `biber/bibtex` what your `.bib` file is, so you are missing `\addbibresource{yourbibfile.bib}`.

Comment: Since you are using Overleaf, the system will automatically run the correct bibliography tool for you, so there is pretty much no reason to use `backend=bibtex,` instead of the default `backend=biber,`. You can only use all of `biblatex`'s features with Biber, with BibTeX you will be limited in what you can do. The example shown in the question is missing an `\addbibresource` and doesn't cite anthying as Alan points out, but otherwise looks OK. Please show us the `.bib` entry of a problematic entry, and add the `.blg` file to your question ...

Comment: ... You can obtain the `.blg` in the same way as described in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/462314/35864 for the `.bbl`. The `.blg` is the log file produced by BibTeX or Biber and should explain why certain entries are dropped. Note that only entries that are `\cite`d or `\nocite`d appear in the bibliography.

Comment: Only references that are `\cite`d will appear in the bibliography. If you want to add an entry to the bibliography without citing it explicitly, you can use `\nocite{<entrykey>}` with `\nocite{*}` you add all available entries to the bibliography, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17128/. The second reference should not be cited with only the title, it should also show an author-year label, but without the code of the `.bib` entry it is hard to say what went wrong. Can you recompile from scratch/clear the cache (http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/479736/) What do the `.log` and `.blg` files say?

Comment: Any news here? Could you solve your problem?

Comment: Thank you for all the comments. It helped me solve the problem. When I was using \cite it was still printing my references twice. But with \nocite my problem is solved. Thank you all once again for your help.